# how do i calculate workhours from single timestamp objects

Tags: c#, .net, time

I'm trying to calculate work hours from timestamps against a timeprofile

```
    public static TimeSpan GetMonth(User u, DateTime start)
    {
        MyContext context = new MyContext();
        var user = context.Users.Include(u => u.Zeitstempel).FirstOrDefault();
        TimeSpan saldo = new TimeSpan(0);
        TimeSpan soll = new TimeSpan(0);
        var zp = u.Zeitprofil.Zeitslots.Where(z => z.StartDate.Month == start.Month && z.EndDate.Month == start.Month);
        foreach (var z in zp)
        {
            soll.Add(z.EndDate.Subtract(z.StartDate));
        }

        var orderedTimestamps = u.Tokens.FirstOrDefault().Zeiterfassung
            .Where(z => z.Timestamp.Date >= start.Date && z.Timestamp.Date <= start.AddMonths(1))
            .OrderBy(z => z.Timestamp.Date)
            .ThenByDescending(z => z.Typ)
            .ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedTimestamps.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var currentTimestamp = orderedTimestamps[i];
            var nextTimestamp = orderedTimestamps[i + 1];

            if (currentTimestamp.Typ != nextTimestamp.Typ)
            {
                var timeDifference = nextTimestamp.Timestamp - currentTimestamp.Timestamp;
                saldo.Add(timeDifference);
            }
        }

        return soll - saldo;
    }
```

Saldo is always is always `00:00:00`

```
soll.Add(z.EndDate.Subtract(z.StartDate));
```

even though substracting the values of end with start will result in a valid timespan value of a few hours for every iteration.

Comment: TimeSpan is a struct you will have to write `soll = soll.Add(xx);`

Comment: Oh, i see, thanks alot.